# Can anyone help me figure out why VScode is saying that it cannot find module?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ben/Desktop/GA/unit2/week5/GA_Project_2/QuotaQuest/index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.8.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I am trying to make a simple "to-do" app using vanilla JS and express, mongoose, and MongoDB. I am trying to start my server but I keep getting this error. My server was working fine for most of the project and I honestly don't know when it stopped working. I am also using Webpack. I have a backend that was connecting fine until I started having this error. I am also using VScode, I have tried doing another "npm i", double-checked dependencies, and tried different `PORT` numbers as well.

Has anyone else run into these issues?

Comment: It is better to add as much information as you can about your work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please include the command you are using to run your code? Also include the filename of the javascript code you are trying to run along with the file structure of your code if any.

Anyway, It might be because you are just running `nodemon` without specifying the entry point of your application. Nodemon assumes it to be `index.js` while it might the case that your filename is `main.js`.